# Error by double to string and back in bukit 1.13

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

i want to let the player in bukkit minecraft 1.13 solve a equation for x,
i wrote a generator and its working fine. But there are fractions possible as answers so i thought i could get the players answer, check if its a fraction, convert it to a double, back to a string and see if the fraction in decimal equals the solution:

```
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("math")) {
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        if(mathPlayer.contains(p.getName())) {
            String eing = args[0];
            String eing2 = "";
            String eingf = "";
            double vergl = 0.0;
            if(eing.contains("/")) {
                eing2 = eing.replace(",", ".");
                vergl = Double.parseDouble(eing2);
                eingf = Double.toString(vergl).replace(".", ",");
            } else {
                eingf = eing;
            }
            int in = mathPlayer.indexOf(p.getName());
            String ergeb = mathAnswer.get(in); 
            if(ergeb.contains(eingf)) {

                    World w = p.getWorld();
                    w.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ENTITY_EXPERIENCE_ORB_PICKUP, 10, 1);
                    p.sendMessage("§8[§cMATH§8] §aCongratulations!");

            } else {
                p.sendMessage("§8[§cMATH§8] §7Wrong: Solution: " + ergeb);
            }
            mathPlayer.remove(in);
            mathAnswer.remove(in);
        } else {
        String equation = genequation(p);
        sender.sendMessage("§8[§cMATH§8] §7Solve for x: §a" + equation);
        p.sendMessage("§8[§cMATH§8] §7Enter answer with /math <answer>!");
        }
return false;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code i believe that you have asked the user to enter a fraction and not a decimal. However, a fraction needs to be converted to decimal before you can check it.

Easiest way to do this I believe would be like so:

```
double partA = Double.parseDouble(args[0].substring(0, args[0].indexOf("/")));
```

`double partB = Double.parseDouble(args[0].substring(args[0].indexOf("/") + 1))`

```
double answer = partA / partB
```

This is approximate and typed on an ipad but them you would compare it to the answer of the question.

Also, but confused as why you return false at the end instead of true.

**Edit:**
Use ChatColor.COLOR_CHAR for the color symbol as that could cause issues later down the line